# Why do I get different CDFs for the same geometric r. v.?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X$ is a r.v., a number of tosses until the coin lands Heads for the first time, including the toss that lands the Heads. $P(Heads) = p$.

I need to find the CDF. I use 2 ways and get different results, which makes no sense because they should be the same.

1) $p_X(x)=(1-p)^{x-1}p$

$F_X(x)=P(X\le x)=\sum_{k=1}^{x}(1-p)^{k-1}p$. Because I don't know how to compute sums manually, I feed it to Wolfram and it says that the sum of it equals $1-(1-p)^x$

2) $F_X(x)=P(X\le x)=1-P(X> x)=1-\sum_{x=k+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{x-1}p=1-(1-p)^{x+1}$

It turns out that the CDFs are almost the same except for the power of $(1-p)$, which should also be the same.

What's wrong and which answer is correct?

Comment: How did you compute the second sum?

Comment: I didn't, I used a Wolfram-based site. Unfortunately, I can't compute sums manually (I don't know series).

Comment: Well, that one is wrong.

Comment: Why so? I also watched the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPh8pFVcQuo , it also has the power of $(x+1)$.

Comment: Look at the pmf of the Geometric distribution [(in the table on the right)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). There are two parameterizations; you are using the first, the video is using the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sum_{k=x+1}^\infty (1-p)^{k-1}p = (1-p)^x
$$
not $(1-p)^{x+1}.$

I think you got your indices confused because $x$ in the second line should not be in the exponent of the summed powers of $(1-p)$; it should be $(1-p)^{\color{red}{k}+1}$